# Как сделать повтор функции в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть функция `open()`. Мне нужно, чтобы когда пользователю предлагают заново её воспроизвести, чтобы он нажимал на цифру 1 и она всегда воспроизводилась до тех пор, пока он не нажмёт любую другую клавишу, чтобы программа завершилась

```
open()

numberS = input("Желаете продолжить?\n"
                  "Если да, то нажмите 1, если нет, то любую клавишу ")
```

Пытаюсь делать

```
while numberS == 1:
    open()
    numberS += 1
```

Но в итоге она просто завершается.

Как сделать, чтобы она была бесконечной в том случае, если всегда нажимать на `1`?

Comment: input() возвращает строку, numberS == 1 никогда не выполнится... проверку на выход не пробовали поставить в open()?

Comment: В Вашем примере numberS += 1 будет всегда увеливаться на 1. 2..3.. 4.. и тд что не равно 1. поэтому и завершается.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Ну или так:

```
def open():
    print('in open() now')


while input('Желаете продолжить?\nЕсли да, то нажмите 1, если нет, то любую клавишу ') == "1":
    open()
```

Answer (score 1):

Если `open()` вызывается всегда и потом повторяется вызов при вводе "1", можно так:

```py
def open():
    print('in open() now')

while True:
    open()
    numberS = input('Желаете продолжить?\nЕсли да, то нажмите 1, если нет, то любую клавишу ')
    if numberS != '1':
        break
```

Comment: только `if numberS != '1'`

Comment: @Kers Да, конечно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Может поможет...

```
def open():
    print("Функция open")

open()
while True:

    numberS = int(input("Желаете продолжить?\n"
                    "Если да, то нажмите 1, если нет, то любую клавишу "))

    if numberS == 1:
        open()
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Если numberS используется только для проверки введенного значения, то в число можно не переводить.

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос нужно будет использовать библиотеку [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).
Эта библиотека нужна для управления потоками и процессами.

```
import threading


def open():
    # do smth
    return ''


def quest():
    q = input('Желаете продолжить?\n" \
                  "Если да, то нажмите 1, если нет, то любую клавишу')
    if q != '1':
        return quest()


t1 = threading.Thread(target=quest)
t1.start()

while t1.is_alive():
    open()
```

Если вы в дальнейшем захотите использовать бинд клавиш, то бишь получить полный доступ к клаве, то вам подойдет библиотека [keybooard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/).Это я к тому, если у вы захотите приостановить программу с помощью клавиш, а не ввода через input().